# openshift default url to redirect to my domain name

Tags: openshift, redirect

I installed wordpress in an OpenShift free small gear. Excited and trying things out. so my installation can be reached at wpapp-wpapp.rhcloud.com and it works fine. I added another alias there such as mydomain.com (no www in front). Now in my DNS I have my @ host name pointing to wpapp-wpapp.rhcloud.com as CNAME and www host name is pointing to mydomain.com (no www in front) as URL Redirect since I want www.mydomain.com to go to mydomain.com. All this is working fine.

The question is when I place in address bar wpapp-wpapp.rhcloud.com it still goes to wpapp-wpapp.rhcloud.com. Can I make wpapp-wpapp.rhcloud.com go to mydomain.com. Is this even possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via .htaccess.

Edit `.openshift/config/.htaccess`, adding the block starting with "Redirect any host that is...":

```
RewriteEngine on 

# Uncomment the following lines to force HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Redirect any host that is not example.com to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [L,R]

# WordPress Defaults
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

See the [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html) for more info on .htaccess re-writes.

Comment: @user3708270 you should 'Accept' this answer by since you thanked him... then this question will appear with a green checkmark as your accepted answer